# How to sum value of checked changed checkbox jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a table, each checkbox contains a value,  and I want to sum value of the checkbox.

**Example:**

Candy and Water is checked : count = 2 , Candy, food and water is checked : count = 5 , checkbox is unchecked : count = 0 . 
I think i must two event , event of each checkbox (.checkbox1) and event of checkbox (.check_all).

**Javascript**

```
      var count = 0;
            $(".checkbox1").change(function() {
                var table_abc = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox1");
                for (var i = 0; table_abc[i]; ++i) {
                    if (table_abc[i].checked) {
                        count += table_abc[i].value;
                    }
                }
           });

alert(count);
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="div_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th><input type="checkbox" class="check_all" id="chk_all" /></th>
            <th>Check All</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="candy" value="2" /></td>
            <td>Candy</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="food" value="3" /></td>
            <td>Food</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" id="water" value="0" /></td>
            <td>Water</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But it seems not working. Can you tell me how to wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I moved declaration of variable `count` inside the `change` function to avoid invalid value in repeating the checked-unchecked

Then you should cast the value of checkbox to a numeric so your summation gives correct values

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamed_badr/qwfo25kt/), it works

Comment: @BrianCrist did you check the fiddle !? http://jsfiddle.net/mohamed_badr/qwfo25kt/

Comment: I checked and ran it and it seems to me that it gives the expected output, could you explain in detail which part is not working with you ?

Answer (score 3):

here is your script, a little bit improved
i'm using here the jquery **.prop()** method to get the checked property of each  element,
and instead of performing concatenation directly with the value of count 
you have to use `Number(number)` or `parseInt(number,base)` in order to tell js engine,  hey i want it to be an arithmetic operation and not a concatenation

here is your snippet of code improved  :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 var count;

            $(".checkbox1").change(function() {
                count = 0;

                var table_abc = $('.checkbox1');

                for (var i = 0; i < table_abc.length ; ++i) {


                    if ($(table_abc[i]).prop('checked')) {
                        count += parseInt($(table_abc[i]).val(),10);
                    }
                }

            console.log(count);

           });



});
```

we are logging to the screen the value of **count** each time a checkbox(with class checkbox1) state is changed

Comment: I try it , but the value of count = 0 . See console log

Comment: For me it is working perfectly, try to check them all and see what you get in the browser console

Answer (score 2):

Use below snippets of code

```js
var count = 0;

            $('input[type="checkbox"]').on("change", function() {
               count = 0;
                if($(this).hasClass('check_all')){
                  
                  $('input[type="checkbox"][class="checkbox1"]').prop('checked',true);
                   $('input[type="checkbox"][class="checkbox1"]').each(function(){
                  
                      count += parseInt($(this).val());
                     
                    });
                  
                  }else{
                    $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function(){
                  
                      count += parseInt($(this).val());
                    });
                  }
              
              alert(count);
           });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="div_table" >
<thead>
<tr>
<th><input type="checkbox" class="check_all" id="chk_all" /></th>
<th>Check All</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1"  id="candy" value="2" /></td>
<td>Candy</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1"  id="food" value="3" /></td>
<td>Food</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1"  id="water" value="0" /></td>
<td>Water</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh, I'm sory but it's not working . Can you try it ?

Comment: @BrianCrist it's working properly... `run code snippet` and then check

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript code seems wrong. Try following

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".checkbox1").change(function() {
        var count = 0;
        var table_abc = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox1");
        for (var i = 0; table_abc[i]; ++i) {
            if (table_abc[i].checked) {
                count += parseInt(table_abc[i].value);
            }
        }
        alert(count);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily iterate over all your checkboxes using the jquery [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function like this:

```
(function($){
  $("input[name='opt']").change(function() {
    count = 0;
    $("input[name='opt']").each(function(index, checkbox){
      if(checkbox.checked)
        count += parseInt(checkbox.value) // convert to integer
    })

    alert(count);
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Few things to pay attention to:

1. `$("input[name='opt']").change` binds all the input checkboxes with `name='opt'` to the provided event handler.
2. The `count` variable is moved inside the `change` event handler, because it needs to be reset to 0 and re-calculated everytime a checkbox is changed.
3. `$("input[name='opt']").each(function(index, checkbox)` iterates through all the input checkboxes with `name='opt'`.
4. To correctly sum the values, you will need to use `parseInt` to convert your string value to integer.
5. Instead of using `class="checkbox1"`, I use `name='opt'` in my codes to group all the checkboxes together.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/ucsfL9p9/) for complete HTML and JS codes.

Comment: Look it's ok , but when i try , it's not working @@.